# day of month must be between 1 and last day of month error

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I write a code about to determine incorret data but I get error messages. Info about data, date columns have type of number, so I have to change them to date. Ex: 10322->01.03.2022

Here is my code;

```
select *
  from (select *****_date,
               *****_hold_no,
               case
                 when length(*****_end_date) = 5 then
                  to_date(lpad(*****_end_date, 6, '0'), 'ddmmyy')
                 else
                  to_date(*****_end_date, 'ddmmyy')
               end as *****_end_date,
               case
                 when length(*****_start_date) = 5 then
                  to_date(lpad(*****_start_date, 6, '0'), 'ddmmyy')
                 else
                  to_date(*****_start_date, 'ddmmyy')
               end as *****_start_date
          from ods_****.*****
         where *****_KW_GLAC = ' '
           and *****_KW_CAAC is not null) A
 where *****_end_date<*****_start_date
```

and it turns the error of "day of month must be between 1 and last day of month".

But if I change the condition of  *****_end_date<*****_start_date to *****_end_date>*****_start_date, I do not get any error message and query works. What can be the problem? Thanks

Reason behind the error message

Comment: Do **NOT** obfuscate your code in such a way that it becomes syntactically invalid. We don't care what you put in place of the `*****`s, just [edit] your question and put something there so your code can be parsed.

Comment: Also, you have tagged SQL Server and Oracle. They are different RDBMS, which one are you using?

Comment: Clean and transform your data at ingest time, not at report time.  By all means keep the raw form of the data, but also populate a column that uses an actual date based datatype.  That column can then be meaningfully indexed. Compute time is reduced through use of the index and not having to reconstitute the date every single time. Code becomes easier to write, read and maintain.  Failed conversions can be detected and isolated at ingest time and raised for automated or manual interventions.  It's literally a win win win win win win solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not store dates as strings; change the table to store them as `DATE`s and then you can only store valid values and do not have to perform any type conversions.

However, since you have them as strings, don't use a `CASE` expression and instead, just use `LPAD` on all the values to ensure everything has the correct length (and, from Oracle 12.2, can use `VALIDATE_CONVERSION` to check that the can be converted to a date):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT obfuscated_date,
         obfuscated_hold_no,
         TO_DATE(LPAD(obfuscated_end_date, 6, '0'), 'ddmmyy') AS obfuscated_end_date,
         TO_DATE(LPAD(obfuscated_start_date, 6, '0'), 'ddmmyy') AS obfuscated_start_date
  FROM   ods_obfuscated.obfuscated
  WHERE  obfuscated_KW_GLAC = ' '
  AND    obfuscated_KW_CAAC is not null
  AND    VALIDATE_CONVERSION(LPAD(obfuscated_start_date, 6, '0') AS DATE, 'ddmmyy') = 1
  AND    VALIDATE_CONVERSION(LPAD(obfuscated_end_date, 6, '0') AS DATE, 'ddmmyy') = 1
) A
WHERE  obfuscated_end_date < obfuscated_start_date
```

---

You can also see the invalid values using:

```sql
SELECT obfuscated_date,
       obfuscated_hold_no,
       obfuscated_end_date,
       obfuscated_start_date
FROM   ods_obfuscated.obfuscated
WHERE  obfuscated_KW_GLAC = ' '
AND    obfuscated_KW_CAAC is not null
AND    (  VALIDATE_CONVERSION(LPAD(obfuscated_start_date, 6, '0') AS DATE, 'ddmmyy') = 0
       OR VALIDATE_CONVERSION(LPAD(obfuscated_end_date, 6, '0') AS DATE, 'ddmmyy') = 0
       )
```

Comment: Thanks but I cannot change the table because it was hold in banking system, I cannot not  have any authority to make any change on data types.  I run your code and it works. Thank you for your contribution!

Answer (score 0):

(at least) one of `TO_DATE` function calls fails because value you're working with is evaluated to invalid date.

For example, for January (which has 31 days), you got 32 or 56 or 93 or ...

That kind of problems happens when people store date values as strings - now you have to deal with that.

Error message looks like Oracle; you didn't specify which version you use. If possible, see `on conversion error`, such as

```
SQL> with test (datum) as
  2    (select '13.10.2022' from dual union all
  3     select '32.01.2023' from dual              --> invalid
  4    )
  5  select datum,
  6         to_date(datum default null on conversion error, 'dd.mm.yyyy') date_value
  7  from test;

DATUM      DATE_VALUE
---------- ----------
13.10.2022 13/10/2022
32.01.2023                  --> NULL, as DATUM is invalid

SQL>
```

Now it is easy to filter out values that can't be converted to dates.